# PropertyChanged is always null

Tags: inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

I am binding a Datagrid to Observablecollection.Below is my ObservableCollection class.
But the Property changed is always NULL and it is null even after Making my XAML like this.
Please Guide me in this

Thanks!

`<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} Header = "Serial" />`

```
   public class itemobject 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged( String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        int sno1;
        public int Sno
        {

            get
            { return sno1; }

            set
            {
                if (value != sno1)
                {
                    sno1= value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Sno");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In XAML you should specify which property exactly changed.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Sno} Header = "Serial" />
```

And like i did, you need to create ViewModelBase class.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null) {
            var handle = PropertyChanged;
            handle?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public virtual void Dispose() => PropertyChanged = null;
    }





 public class itemobject : ViewModelBase{
        int sno1;
        public int Sno{
            get => sno1;
            set{
                if (value != sno1){
                    sno1= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Sno));
                }
            }
        }
```